# How to display 1 camera on 2 tkinter windows

Tags: python, tkinter, camera

I am currently doing license plate reading via camera, I want my software to have 2 display screens, 1 for the supervisor, and 1 for the driver to see. I have 2 cameras including face display and license plate display, this is the main window

[image]

code: file tkbutton.py

```
from videocapture import VideoCapture
# Mở chế độ xem nhanh
    def quick_view(self):
        self.IS_quick_view = True
        self.quick_view = self.Cam2.open_new_window()
```

when I press the button to open another window, it displays the camera in the toplevel window, however 1 of the 2 cameras is in the main window will freeze

[image]

This is code in file tkCamera.py

```
class tkCamera(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, window, row, col, width=None, height=None, sources=None, text="", source=0):
        """TODO: add docstring"""

        super().__init__(window)

        self.source = source # source hiện tại đang phát trực tiếp
        self.width  = width # mặc định 400
        self.height = height # mặc định 300
        self.other_sources = sources # Tất cả các source đã khai báo
        self.row= row
        self.col= col
        self.vid = VideoCapture(self.source, self.width, self.height)
     
        self.make_gui_camera(text, window)   

        self.delay = int(100/self.vid.fps)

        print(toast_connected, self.source)
        print('[tkCamera] fps:', self.vid.fps, 'delay:', self.delay)

        self.image = None
        self.running = True
        self.update_frame()
        

    def update_frame(self):
        """TODO: add docstring"""

        # widgets in tkinter already have method `update()` so I have to use different name -

        # Get a frame from the video source
        ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()
        self.frame_toan_canh.update()
        width = self.frame_toan_canh.winfo_width()
        height= self.frame_toan_canh.winfo_height()
        # print(width,height )
        if ret:
            self.image = frame
            resized_image= self.image.resize((width,height), PIL.Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
            self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=resized_image)
            id_image = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor='nw')

        if self.running:
            self.after(self.delay, self.update_frame)
            
    def open_new_window(self):
        self.new_window = another_window(self.vid)
        return self.new_window
        
class another_window():

    def __init__(self, video):
        
        self.vid = video
        self.window = tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.window.title("Chế độ xem nhanh")
        self.window.geometry("1200x800-0-100")
        
        self.window.columnconfigure((0,2),weight=1, uniform="a")
        self.window.columnconfigure(1,weight=4, uniform="a")
        self.window.rowconfigure(0,weight=1, uniform="a")
        
        self.stop = False
        self.make_gui_camera("camera")
        self.running = True
        self.delay = int(100/self.vid.fps)
        self.update_frame_another_window
        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)

    def update_frame_another_window(self):

        # Get a frame from the video source
        ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame2()
        #self.window.deiconify()
        #self.frame_quick_view.update()
        width = self.frame_quick_view.winfo_width()
        height= self.frame_quick_view.winfo_height()
        # print(width,height )
        if ret:
            self.image = frame
            resized_image= self.image.resize((width,height), PIL.Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
            self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=resized_image)
            id_image = self.canvas_another_window.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor='nw')

        if self.running:
            self.window.after(self.delay, self.update_frame_another_window)

    def on_close(self):   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions/methods/variables
        self.running = False
        self.quick_view = False
        self.window.destroy()
```

code in file videocapture.py:

```
class VideoCapture:

    def __init__(self, video_source, width=None, height=None, fps=None):
        """TODO: add docstring"""

        self.video_source = video_source
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.fps = fps

    # Cài đặt trạng thái hoạt động
        self.running = False

        # Đọc frame và lấy các thông số chiều rộng, chiều cao, fps
        self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
        
        if not self.vid.isOpened():
            print("Failed to read frame, retrying connection...")
            self.vid.release()
            time.sleep(1)
            self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
            time.sleep(10000)
            raise ValueError(error_read_frame, video_source)

        if not self.width:
            self.width = int(self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))    # convert float to int
        if not self.height:
            self.height = int(self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))  # convert float to int
        if not self.fps:
            self.fps = int(self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))              # convert float to int

        # Khởi tạo giá trị mặc định cho frame
        self.ret = False
        self.frame = None

        self.convert_color = cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB
        self.convert_pillow = True


        # Khởi tạo thread
        self.running = True
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.process)
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()
        print(threading.active_count())
        print(threading.enumerate())
    
    def process(self):
        """TODO: add docstring"""
        while self.running:
            ret, frame = self.vid.read()
            self.origin_frame= frame
            
            if ret:
                # Hàm imshow phải dùng trong luồng chính, chạy trong thread sẽ gây ra các lỗi ko mong muốn
                # process image
                #frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.width, self.height))

                if self.convert_pillow:
                    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    frame = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame)
            else:
                print(toast_end_stream, self.video_source)
                self.running = False
                break

            # assign new frame
            self.ret = ret
            self.frame = frame


    def get_frame(self):
        return self.ret, self.frame
    
    def get_origin_frame(self):
        return self.ret, self.origin_frame

    # Giải phóng tài nguyên khi kết thúc ghi hình, hàm hủy sẽ được gọi trước khi đóng cửa sổ
    def __del__(self):
        print(toast_end)
        # stop thread
        if self.running:
            self.running = False
            self.thread.join()
        # relase stream
        if self.vid.isOpened():
            self.vid.release()
```

I don't know where the error comes from so I can't handle it, please help me

I think the problem is in the thread, I tried copying the vid object but it still doesn't work

Comment: The argument to `time.sleep()` is in seconds, so why do you sleep that long: `time.sleep(10000)`?

Comment: This argument is in milliseconds. I want to try to connect to the camera every 10 seconds, but it doesn't work, if the camera is turned off unexpectedly then the program crashes, it doesn't reconnect automatically. Haizzz

Comment: See document on [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep).  It is in seconds unless you have overload the function.